# Urban airship takeoff error

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I am using Urban airship in my project but when i write take of code then it shows this error please give me any solutions .

```
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-105
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): Process: com.urbanairship.push.sample, PID: 1427
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:186)
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship.<init>(UAirship.java:107)
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship.executeTakeOff(UAirship.java:302)
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship.access$000(UAirship.java:54)
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship$2.run(UAirship.java:260)
10-15 07:57:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

this is my code

```
 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Optionally, customize your config at runtime:
        //
         AirshipConfigOptions options = new AirshipConfigOptions();
         options.inProduction = false;
         options.developmentAppKey = "******************";
         options.developmentAppSecret = "*******************";

         UAirship.takeOff(this, options);

        UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
           @Override
          public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
              // Perform any airship configurations here

               airship.getPushManager().setPushEnabled(true);
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add .jar file in build-path. If this not helps then post all code.

Comment: it shows error when reach at UAirship.takeOff(this, options);

Comment: check added anser. If any problem then let me know..

Comment: still get problem then try to create new project. add add lib on it

Comment: Sorry for late reply please give me soultuion it is still showing error   PushManager.enablePush();  showing The method enablePush() is undefined for the type PushManager

Comment: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/android.html#add-the-library-to-your-project please refer. check updated code..

Answer (score 1):

I also had ran into this same issue and just figured it out. It turns out that the missing class was added to the API 21 support library. I had been using the API 19 support library and was getting this error.

To fix it you'll need to add the **latest** android-support-v4.jar to your project from the API 21 Android SDK. After you've updated your Android SDK, in Eclipse, you can:

1) Right click on your project
2) Select "Android Tools"
3) Select "Add Support Library..."

Clean, refresh and try again and you should be good to go. Good luck!

Thanks to realepinski's comment from before to help me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on included jar. and `Build path -> add to build path`.
Make sure in project property i.e `properties -> java build path -> order and export` and check included library.

Also check for android-support-v4.jar is refered in project.
`Right click project -> android tools -> Add support library`

Mention your keys details in `assets folder -> airshipconfig.properties`

Use this class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Optionally, customize your config at runtime:
        //
        // AirshipConfigOptions options = new AirshipConfigOptions();
        // options.inProduction = false;
        // options.developmentAppKey = "Your Development App Key";
        // options.developmentAppSecret "Your Development App Secret";
        //
        // UAirship.takeOff(this, options);

        UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
                // Perform any airship configurations here

                airship.getPushManager().setPushEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: PushManager.enablePush();  is not working there is no method like this it is sowing

Comment: i am using the  urbanairship-lib-5.0.1.jar

Comment: and also i am using the PushSample of urban airship which is on GITHUB

Comment: check http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/push/PushManager.html  there is no mehod for ebanlePush

Comment: This error is because of lib reference google-play-service , support v4 lib and urban.jar. Check for  airshipconfig.properties is in assets. If u still getting problem . Then i will get back you. i will need all code .

Comment: Now i have create a saprate sample with single file only MYApplicatoin but still the same error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat

Comment: Make sure to update your android SDK with the latest version of the support library. If you are missing the NotificationManagerCompat and have included the v4 support library then its out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials can be added in two ways

1) by setting in the Application class(as you have done)

2) by adding in assets folder

Add the required Urban Airship library files.

Answer (score 0):

```
****1. Add below code in App****  
public class App extends Application {
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
                airship.getPushManager().setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);
            }
        });
}
}

**2. add file in below path:**
app -> assets -> airshipconfig.properties

**3. In airshipconfig.properties write below code:**
developmentAppKey=************    //  development/Staging Key                                                           developmentAppSecret=**************
productionAppKey=*********     //  Production Key          
productionAppSecret=********
inProduction=true 
developmentLogLevel=DEBUG  //LogLevel is "VERBOSE", "DEBUG", "INFO","WARN","ERROR" or "ASSERT" 
productionLogLevel=ERROR 
fcmSenderId=*******  //FCM Sender ID/Firebase project number
notificationIcon=ic_logo_small  
notificationAccentColor=#000000
notificationChannel=customChannel
```